# How to read file of subprocess output

Tags: python

In this code, subprocess.Popen creates /tmp/test.txt with `date` output.
Why doesn't the 2nd "print lines" work ?
I would appreciate for your help.

```
test]# touch /tmp/test.txt
test]# ./x1.py
/tmp/test.txt
()
/tmp/test.txt
()
test]# ./x1.py
/tmp/test.txt
('Sun Jun 19 15:10:21 PDT 2016\n',)
/tmp/test.txt
()
test]# cat x1.py
#!/usr/bin/python

from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

filename = "/tmp/test.txt"

lines = tuple(open(filename, 'r'))
print filename
print  lines # this is not empty

file_ = open(filename, "w")
Popen("date", shell=True, stdout=file_)
file_.close()

lines = tuple(open(filename, 'r'))
print filename
# why is this empty even if file_ definitely created the /tmp/test.txt ?
print  lines    
test]#
```

Comment: Works fine for me on ubuntu

Comment: Aside: Why are you in a root shell?

Comment: Have you considered `.wait()`ing for the Popen to finish before closing its `stdout`?

Comment: @Tadhg McDonald-Jensen, It worked. Appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `.wait()` for the `Popen` to finish before closing the stdout, otherwise you get undefined behaviour.

```
Popen("date", shell=True, stdout=file_).wait()
#                                       ^ add this part!
```

I can't say for sure how the file was written to *after* you tried to read from it but I imagine that is an implementation detail for your OS.